# spliting the String by first two spaces

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, split

I have read a lot but I am not getting how to get my required String,My String is:
"552 s East and west we are the best"
I want to get "552" in one string "s" in char and all the remaining String after the space 's' in one String,and the position of spaces will be changed every time.Please help.I have tried

```
 messages="552 s East and west we are the best";
    String[] sp=messages.split(" ");
         String threadid=sp[0];
         String status=sp[1];
         String msg=sp.toString();
```

but I am getting something garbage in msg.

Comment: Since you know the parts of the String you want to get why do not get them manually? You should describe the general case as well. Is "s" charachter or merely a symbol for whitespace?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @arjacsoh s is the character it represents message status ,check my edit too.

Comment: **Do not** use 's' for message status, please ^_^.

Comment: You have almost what do you want. But you have to know that sp is an Array so sp.toString() is not going to magically extract the Strings inside it. Try to think another way to achieve this task (in a loop, for example).

Comment: `sp.toString()` only gives the address of the array. Use `Arrays.toString(sp)` instead.

Comment: It is not garbage message. It gives you address of Array. It might be like this `[Ljava.lang.String;@29173ef`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
    String str = "552 s East and west we are the best";
    String[] arr = str.split(" ", 3);
    String partOne = arr[0];
    char partTwo = arr[1].charAt(0);
    String partThree = arr[2];

    System.out.println("part one: "+partOne);
    System.out.println("part two: "+partTwo);
    System.out.println("part three: "+partThree);
```

Out put:

```
 part one: 552
 part two: s
 part three: East and west we are the best
```

Comment: Nice one, really simple yet efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- Read the documentation of [`Sting#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).
- Use [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29):

  Check where the first index of space is, then get the `substring` until the index, and from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
    String x="552 s East and west we are the best";
    String x1[]=x.split(" ",2);
    System.out.println(x1[0]);
    System.out.println(x1[1]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be many way to get it done.One may be *doing sub string your input string by index*,
Other may be -

```
String[] splts = inputString.split("\\s",3);
int number = Integer.parseInt(splts[0]);
String s = splts[1];
String others = splts[2];
```